# Having trouble understanding the comparison test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm having trouble understanding the comparison test,

I know that I need to compare with a series higher or equal for each k >= 1

But how do I know with which serie to compare ? Consider

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4}{3n\sqrt{n}}$$

How can I find with which serie I need to compare to prove the convergence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first comparison that may come to mind is

$$\frac1{n^2} \leqslant \frac1{n\sqrt{n}} \leqslant \frac1{n}.$$

This is not helpful in determining convergence since the upper bounding series$\sum 1/n$ diverges and the lower bounding series $\sum 1/n^2$ converges.

There is no comparison with a series of the form $\sum 1/n^p$ that will help unless you already know that such a series converges for $p > 1$ and diverges for $p \leqslant 1$ by another means (for example, the integral test).  In that case, you have already established that your series, where $p = 1.5$, converges.

In essence, the integral test, is a form of the comparison test.  Since $f(x) = x^{-p}$ is decreasing for $p >0$,

$$\frac1{n^p} \leqslant \int_{n-1}^n x^{-p}\,dx \leqslant \frac1{(n-1)^p},$$

and if $p > 1$,

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac1{n^p} \leqslant \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\int_{n-1}^n x^{-p}\,dx = \int_{1}^{\infty} x^{-p}\,dx = \frac1{p-1}< \infty.$$

Comment: So you would recommend the integral test for solving this one instead of the comparison ?

Comment: @ProgrammerJeff:  The integral test is most expiditious for testing this series. Many analysis books use the "p-series" the first example for application of the integral test. I'm saying above that the comparison test is method of first resort when you immediately recognize a comparative series with known convergence or divergence.  The fractional exponent means that comparison with integral powers of n is not helpful.  You could say $\sum 1/(n \sqrt{n})$ converges by comparison with $\sum 1/n^{1.1}$ assuming you knew the latter converged.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I solved it in a few mins with the integral tests. It seems my real problem is how to know which criteria to use, but I guess this will come with practice. Thanks again !

Comment: You're very welcome.